# Where does an ARM based system find its OS?

Tags: arm, os

I'm not sure if this question is device specific. After some reading I found that you need a bootloader to load the OS. Is there some specific memory address where the code of the OS begins, else how can the bootloader find it? And about the bootloader: is the ARM bootloader really just the code at the reset vector that gets executed when you power on the device?

Comment: Depends of which arm mcu controller you are using...

Comment: You link the reset interrupt to your bootloader in the simplest case. But the bootloader isn't in the vector table

Comment: @OverCoder First of all, don't answer in comments. Second of all, that information is all specific to x86, and doesn't apply to ARM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootloader is indeed the code that gets executed from the reset vector. How it finds the operating system is up to the individual design of the bootloader. For example, it may

- read it from the first sectors of an SD card (like the MS-DOS bootloader)
- read from the start of an EPROM/Flash memory
- read bytes from a UART and interpret as an XMODEM download
- it may configure itself as a USB mass storage device and wait for a download (some LPC parts can do this).

Comment: I'd just like to add something to that: The bootloader is not necessarily linked to the reset vector. Speaking for the FSL i.MX series (which is a "typical" ARM CortexA8/A9 processor) it's the internal ROM code that's responsible for the first tasks. This ROM code will check some pins that determine which source is actually selected. In case of an SD-Card, it will setup the pins, in case for flash, it will setup these pins. Only then will the ROM code hand off to the bootloader (usually to a special section which contains things such as DDR settings, cache settings, ..).

Comment: This is a "multistage" bootloader, where the internal ROM is the first stage. As you say, it also varies between A and M devices.